# MIT Course - Merge Sort - why max number of comparisons made between two sublists is <= length of the longer list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, time-complexity

I'm doing the open MIT Course - Introduction To Computer Science And Programming In Python.
The last class talks about the merge sort algorithm and it's order of growth.
I understand that the complexity is O(n*log (n)) as:

log (n) = number of recursion levels, n = total time required to merge lists per recursion level, where n is the length of the original list.

What I don't understand is the statement in bold when they breakdown the complexity of merging sublists step:

- go through two lists, only one pass
- compare only smallest elements in each sublist
- O(len(left)+len(right)) copied elements
- **O(len(longer list)) comparisons**
- linear in length of the lists

I expected the number of comparisons to be: **the length of both sublists O(len(left) + len(right))** or **the length of both sublists minus 1 O((len(left) + len(right))-1)** because for example:

For these 2 lists:

[1,3,5] and [2,4]

If I want to merge them together I would have to do 4 comparisons and not 3:

1º - 1,2;

2º - 3,2;

3º - 3,4;

4º - 5,4.

Comment: big O notation doesn't work with len(right) or len(left), you should look at it in order of n, which is the size of the input you're getting. also big O notation doesn't count changes by constants (or multiplication) so O(2n) = O(n) = O(n/2) which in your case the size of the *len(right)* or len(left) or the sum are all the same size in that manner. the idea of each iteration goes through all the inputs constant number of times (which is linear) and the number of iteration (as you wrote) is log(n) because you cut the number of elements in each sublist by half.

Comment: O(len(left) +len(right)) = O(len(longer list))

Comment: Your count of comparisons is correct. The maximum number of comparisons is `N-1`, where `N=L+M`. L and M are the lengths of the longer and shorter list respectively. So you are correct to say that the number of comparisons is O(N). The course is also correct to claim that the number of comparisons is O(L), because as pointed out in the other comments O(L) = O(N). But I contend that O(L) is uninformative, since for lists of approximately the same length, the number of comparisons will rarely be less than L and will often be closer to N.